# How to avoid repeated code in promise chain?

Tags: promise, coding-style, code-cleanup

I have a promise chain:

```
Promise
.then(function() {
    if (some condition) {
        Promise.reject("Request cancelled");
    }

    return doSomething1();
})
.then(function() {
    if (some condition) {
        Promise.reject("Request cancelled");
    }

    return doSomething2();
})
.then(function() {
    if (some condition) {
        Promise.reject("Request cancelled");
    }

    return doSomething3();
})
.catch(function(err) {
    if (err == "Request cancelled") {
        // err handling here
    }
})
```

In every .then(), there's same piece of code checking whether to break the promise chain:

```
// repeated code
if (some condition) {
    Promise.reject("Request cancelled");
}
```

I need to do this because I wanna stop rest of the async calls immediately once I catch the error so that the app can save some memory and time. But it looks really messy and redundant.

So my question is: is there a way to write this code and avoid repeated code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not going to build this logic into `doSomething1()` and `doSomething2()` so that they themselves return a rejected promise when the condition is met, then the simplest thing I can think of is to change this:

```
p.then(function() {
    if (some condition) {
        Promise.reject("Request cancelled");
    }

    return doSomething1();
}).then(function() {
    if (some condition) {
        Promise.reject("Request cancelled");
    }

    return doSomething2();
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

to something like this:

```
p.then(checkCondition).then(function() {
    return doSomething1().then(checkCondition);
}).then(function() {
    return doSomething2().then(checkCondition);
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

Where, you define `checkCondition()` to have your shared condition in it:

```
function checkCondition(val)
    if (some condition) {
        return Promise.reject("Request cancelled");
    }
    return val;
}
```

---

Or you could wrap your promise returning functions:

```
p.then(checkCondition).then(function() {
    return checkCondition(doSomething1());
}).then(function() {
    return checkCondition(doSomething2());
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

Where `checkCondition()` is like this:

```
function checkCondition(p) {
    return p.then(function(val) {
        if (some condition) {
            return Promise.reject("Request cancelled");
        }
        return val;
    });
}
```

---

If there's really nothing but sequencing these async function calls and checking that particular condition on them, then you can automate it all by passing in an array of functions and sequencing the array, checking the condition on each result.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) I'll try them out

Comment: @Max - if this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.